# ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, codenameone

> ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid.
>   "The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate
>   your API prior to delivery

I got the above error each time I want to upload the new version of my app to iTunes connect. I am using application loader for the upload. My application was developed using `Codename` one.

Please, any help will be appreciated. I have been on this for a long time now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An invalid binary can happen for several reasons (the analysis file isn't the problem):

- Outdated application loader - this is the most common reason. Make sure your Mac OS X version is up to date and the application loader tool is updated
- Using debug instead of appstore built IPA
- Incorrect provisioning - if you used provisioning or certificate incorrectly. This can happen if you re-run the certificate wizard before uploading the app as it can invalidate the existing certificate or regenerate provisioning

Comment: Please Shai, I just downloaded version 3.0 of application loader from app submit page. I don't really understand what you mean by my" is iOS version is up to date?"  Again, I used IPA file for app store. But I think I changed my certificate when I got an error in the first place. Do I need to use certification wizard to create new certificate and provisioning profile and override the one in my apple store account?

Comment: 3.0 is very old. I'm currently at 3.5 and I'm not sure it's the latest. I meant make sure your Mac OS  desktop is up to date.

Comment: It worked. I was using stand alone application loader version 3.0 which is too old. I then used the application loader in my xcode 7.2 with the version 3.4 and it worked. Shai you are doing a nice job here.

Answer (score 3):

If your binary file .IPA is validated.
Than use the **Application Loader v3.6**

and you will be fine.

Comment: This is bad advice, as it will inevitably become stale -- even if Application Loader 3.6 is the correct version right now, it will certainly not be the right version a year from now. (Maybe even sooner.)

Comment: But this did help me out! so maybe you can just try when you don't know what to do~just an option.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue using Fastlane by uploading a binary file .IPA and setting an `app_identifier` that didn't correspond with the .IPA file I was sending.

My error message was `ERROR ITMS-4241: "App is Removed or Deleted. Apps can't be validated or submitted while they're removed or deleted." at SoftwareAssets`.

So I just fixed the `app_identifier` in the [`Appfile`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/Appfile/).