# How to upload app on testFlight

Tags: xcode, testflight

I want to upload build on testFlight with the Xcode But getting error every time.
How can i upload it by Application loader
what option should I select when creating IPA to upload it by Application Loader

[image]

Comment: mention the error..!!!

Comment: What is the error? Btw, you need to select the 3rd option, "Save for Enterprise Deployment".

Comment: I want to upload it only for beta testing

Comment: You have to select first option for Beta Testing, But you have to mention the error so that we can suggest you....

Comment: Upload a store build (first option) for TestFlight. The same build can be tested on TestFlight, and then released to the store without changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create .ipa file using Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

You upload a app as normal... Testflight is a feature you can setup in iTunes Connect. Thus you use the first option, and then in iTunes Connect you do the rest.

After upload to iTunes Connect, you should have a build available in iTunes Connect Testflight area...

[image]

There you follow the prompts, it is a very simple process to follow...

Comment: But I am not be able upload app on itune neither Xcode nor Application Loader

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406751/error-itms-90168-the-binary-you-uploaded-was-invalid...  Note that your issue is to do with the binary upload, and not at the testflight, as originally explain...

Comment: Do you have a App Store Distribution Profile, as mentioned by @hariszaman, for deploying your apps?

Comment: Ya every thing is OK.
If I create IPA With Adhoc then working for me but, when I Create a IPA with Appstore Deployment Then it fire above error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149223/discussion-between-burnie777-and-pintu-rajput).

Comment: @PintuRajput: Do not edit an answer to ask a question!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload an app signed with Development profile or Adhoc Distribution to App store. For uploading to App store you application should be signed with **App Store Distribution Profile**

Answer (score 0):

When you are building a TestFlight build, you don't need to 'Export'. Once you got to the 'Organizer' select 'Upload to App Store'. Then it will ask you choose the team. Select your team or select 'use local signing assets' if you have imported certificates from another mac.

If your build has no issues, you will be able to upload it to the App Store.

[image: Upload to App Store]