# ERROR ITMS-90680: "The binary you uploaded was invalid.”

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

trying to validate iOS app but got ERROR ITMS-90680: "The binary you uploaded was invalid.”

had tried adding run script at build phase but no luck, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: There can be multiple reasons, primarily that your **stand alone application loader** version is old

Comment: check it  apps version or plist data ,,,

Comment: is it any updated version of App or you are uploading  first time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406751/error-itms-90168-the-binary-you-uploaded-was-invalid

Answer (score 0):

Check , you've already uploaded another app version to the store, now you'll need to create a new version and upload that.

Comment: check, no other app with higher version on itunesconnect but still got error

Comment: @LeoChen    did u specify the build number and the version number from xcode? Are u using application loader for the upload?

Comment: i had tried using both application loader and xcode to upload the ipa, but both returned same error. the build numbers are all set to 1 but i change the version number with higher number, still error.

Comment: @Mayank Baiswar yes i did, it was because the invalid import of prop-types, I update to the latest react-native version and change the import PropTypes from 'prop-types' instead of react (of all components and sub-components). good luck!

Answer (score -2):

have you build your application for release. To do that the command is

```
tns build ios --release --for-device
```

More info about the build command (and any other command) can be seen via

```
tns build ios --help
```

If this does not resolve your case, please verify that you have gone through the steps described in publishing for iOS and also send us the content of your package.json file.